# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'xxx' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: java, angularjs, web-services, paypal, get

I tried to integrate paypal payment gateway into my application.

Simply I am calling java webservice using angularjs get method.

Below the angularjs http get method code

```
  $http({
            method : 'GET',
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/xxxx/redirect'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.info("success");
        });
```

The Java side code tried is-

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public ModelAndView method(Payment pPayment) {
     String amount=pPayment.getAmount();
     String url="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=wipro-seller@gmail.com&first_name=smartCity&city=Madurai&state=Tamilnadu&item_name=shirt&amount=10&night_phone_a=9513335437&item_name=shirt&address1=wipro-seller@gmail.com&business=k.tapankumar@gmail.com&quantity=1&currency=USD";
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + url);

    }
```

I am calling Paypal test account url from Java server side only, but still I am getting below error

```
  XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=wipro-se…o-seller@gmail.com&business=k.tapankumar@gmail.com&quantity=1&currency=USD. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Kindly Let me know where I did wrong..

Comment: this is a CORS error probably you need to change on server side to include response header. See the flowchart [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) probably it will help you understand CORS

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enable cross origin requests (CORS) for your HTTP requests.

Spring Documentation documents on how to enable this really well. Find it [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cors.html). I suggest you read through it and try it out. If it still doesn't work, post here.

More on CORS [here](http://enable-cors.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You should allow cross origin request from client side as well.

try to run after installing a chrome plugin for cross origin

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

this is the link for the one which i use.

Also you should change your headers to allow cors like this

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```